# Leave Korean recovery mode

Tags: recovery-mode, lg-g2

I tried to enter the recovery mode on my LG G2 smartphone by pressing Volume Up + Volume Down + Power and then releasing Power, as described [here](http://www.mobiany.com/how-to-wipe-the-cache-partition-on-lg-g2.html). My goal was to clear the system cache, *not* to perform a hard reset.

Unfortunately, the recovery mode is in Korean (I suppose):

[image: Recovery Mode in Korean]

As I cannot read the options, I am afraid of accidentally deleting all my data.

Can anyone tell me which option refers to "clear cache"? Or, if this option does not exist, is one of the options "abort/exit"? The main goal is to leave this screen without erasing my user data.

In case this should be relevant: I think the phone uses Lollipop, but (for obvious reasons) I cannot check this at the moment.

Comment: @benjaminS Are you sure that pressing power won't select to currently highlighted option?

Comment: Yeah you're right - might be to dangerous. good point. The recovery does look weird though... I've watched a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ogBvzbPikc) and pressing any button other than the power button should cancel the recovery

Comment: Not helpful, but it's not Chinese. To me it looks like Korean – which makes much sense cosindering where LG comes from. Have you tried contacting their support?

Comment: @benjaminS Thank you for your effort. I watched to video too. However, in my case the Volume buttons just scroll through the options and Power (supposedly) selects.

Comment: @Izzy I didn't contact support yet, but I'll try now. Thanks for the hint that it looks Korean. This could explain why I couldn't make any progress using Chinese OCR.

Comment: Glad my hint helped solving the issue! It basically is the more square-like characters suggesting Korean, together with the fact that LG is a Korean company :)

Comment: @Izzy Thank you! I'll try to remember these hints for next time (hopefully: never …).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [@Izzy's comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155636/leave-korean-revovery-mode#comment199432_155636) that the text looks Korean I could solve the issue:

A Korean OCR online tool recognized the characters in the last option as 취소 which Google translates as "Cancel". Choosing the last option actually restarted the phone (without any data loss).